# Update list when redux store changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-virtualized

I am trying to update the list when my redux store changes but for some odd reason it isn't. I have to manually refresh the page to see my changes. Here's the snippet of my List component and rowRenderer.

```js
    <InfiniteLoader
                    isRowLoaded={this._isRowLoaded}
                    loadMoreRows={this._loadMoreRows}
                    rowCount={visibleRequest.length}
                  >
                    {({ onRowsRendered, registerChild }) => (
                      <AutoSizer>
                        {({ height, width }) => (
                          <List
                            ref={registerChild}
                            className="List"
                            height={height}
                            rowHeight={listRowHeight}
                            onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                            rowCount={rowCount}
                            rowRenderer={this._rowRenderer}
                            width={width}
                          />
                        )}
                      </AutoSizer>
                    )}
                  </InfiniteLoader>
                  
                  
                  

_rowRenderer = ({ index, key, style }) => {
    const { loadedRowsMap, selected } = this.state;
    const row = this.getDatum(index);
    let content;
    if (loadedRowsMap[index] === STATUS_LOADED) {
      content = row;
    } else {
      content = (
        <div className="placeholder" style={{ width: _.random(100, 200) }} />
      );
    }
    return (
      <PendingChat
        key={key}
        content={content}
        style={style}
        row={row}
        {...this.props}
      />
    );
  };
```

Comment: is any of the `List` props changing? I see you have `rowCount={visibleRequest.length}` and `rowCount={rowCount}`. Does `rowCount` stay the same? Try passing a prop to `List` that changes when you want to trigger a rerender, it can be any prop additional to those, if you don't want to change `rowCount`

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I ran into the same problem. Its because the references to your objects don't change when you do

```
const row = this.getDatum(index);
    let content;
    if (loadedRowsMap[index] === STATUS_LOADED) {
      content = row;
    }
```

Take a look at [immutability](https://wecodetheweb.com/2016/02/12/immutable-javascript-using-es6-and-beyond/).

Comment: @Shizam Gupta I don't understand you. Can you try and explain better. Thanks.

Comment: The reference to your your object does not actually change. when you do this. 
You need to change the reference to your object when you update it. 
That way the page re-renders with the updated object value